# Use compareTo() with Comparable<T> interface and arraylist

Tags: java, interface, comparable

I am doing an assignment that requires me to use the Comparable interface and use compareTo() to see if two numbers are equal. I am also required to use an ArrayList but I don't understand how to execute the compareTo() in the test class.
This is my code so far.

```
public abstract class Homework3 implements Comparable<Homework3>
{
// instance variables
public int pagesRead;
public String typeHomework;

public Homework3()
{
    pagesRead = 0;
    typeHomework = "none";
}

public int getPagesRead()
{
    return pagesRead;
}

public void setPagesRead(int p)
{
    pagesRead = p;
}

public String getTypeHomework()
{
    return typeHomework;
}

public void setTypeHomework(String t)
{
    typeHomework = t;
}

public abstract void createAssignment(int p);

public int compareTo(Homework3 p)
{
    if (pagesRead < p.pagesRead)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (pagesRead == p.pagesRead)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
}


public class MyMath3 extends Homework3
{
public MyMath3()
{
    super();
}

public void createAssignment(int p)
{
    pagesRead = p;
    typeHomework = "Math";
}

public String toString()
{
    return typeHomework + " - must read " + pagesRead + " pages.";
}
}
```

There are 3 more classes called MyEnglish3, MyScience3, and MyJava3 but there are basically the same as the math class. The only thing that changes is the type of homework. I'm trying to print out a statement that says "Homework for math and english have the same number of pages" as the last line after printing the amount of pages for each homework (Math, Science, English, Java). I have to use compareTo() but I really don't know how I can compare the page numbers of each object in the arraylist. This is my test class.

```
public class TestHomework3
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    List<Homework3> test = new ArrayList<Homework3>();
    test.add(new MyMath3());
    test.add(new MyScience3());
    test.add(new MyEnglish3());
    test.add(new MyJava3());
    for (Homework3 p : test)
    {
        if (p instanceof MyMath3) 
        {
            p.createAssignment(4);
        } 
        else if (p instanceof MyScience3) 
        {
            p.createAssignment(6);
        } 
        else if (p instanceof MyEnglish3)
        {
            p.createAssignment(4);
        }
        else if (p instanceof MyJava3) 
        {
            p.createAssignment(5);
        }
        System.out.println(p);
    } 
}
}
```

Should I change the for each loop? Or is there another way that I can compare the page number of each type of homework while still using the arraylist and the Comparable interface?

Comment: What is the purpose of your loop? You create your homeworks, and at that point know what they are. You then loop and try and find out again what they are - this is obviously pointless.

Comment: I also do not understand the question - do you want to sort the list? Something else? Where does `compareTo` come into it?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I looped it to set the pages for each type of Homework and I need to use compareTo() to compare which two type of Homework has the same amount of pages.

Comment: Why not set the pages _before_ you dump them in the list?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I just did what you said. Thank you for the advice. Now how should I compare it?

Comment: Call the `compareTo` method you defined? I don't really know what you want to achieve with the comparison. Sounds like you want to sort and then output things with the same size.

Comment: Yeah, I want output the things with the same number of pages but when I call the compareTo, it just gives me Math is equal to Math not Math is equal to English.

Comment: Indeed - so what can you do with that information to achieve your goal? Given a pile of banknotes and asked to group all the ones of the same value how would you do that?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I would separate the big pile into little piles with each different value getting its own pile.

Comment: I am still unclear, do you want to sort the list?
1. Make instance variables private as you are using getter-setters
2. change compareTo() method :-
"pagesRead < p.pagesRead" to " this.getPagesRead() < p.getPagesRead()"

Comment: I don't want to sort it. I just want to get the two that are equal. So in this case the math and the english should be printed as the same because they have the same number of pages. I'll go make it private and add this.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thank you so much for your help!!! I figured it out.

Comment: @KushalShinde Thank you for the suggestions!! I figured it out now.